# TextFormField looses focus on redraw

Tags: flutter, dart

Im developing a search UI in flutter that queries an external API for data then shows it in a list.

Ive adopted a responsive design pattern from a  [Filled Stacks tutorial](https://www.filledstacks.com/post/a-responsive-ui-architecture-solution-with-provider/)

I call the api in the "onChanged" when i detect that the input has 3 or more characters.

As soon as the call completes the UI is redrawn , the text field looses focus,the keyboard retracts and the results are shown.

This works really well if you search query contains exactly 4 characters, but is a royal pain as every additional character cases the results to reload.

Searching leads me to believe that this could relate to missing or incorrect Keys. I have added multiple UniqueKey/ValueKey in an attempt to resolve this but nothing has worked.

I hope someone can help

```
class SearchMobilePortrait
    extends BaseModelWidget<SearchViewModel> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  double _height = 0;
  double _width = 0;

  SearchViewModel viewmodel = serviceLocator<SearchViewModel>();
  static final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  static final _searchKey = UniqueKey();
  TextEditingController queryController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, CompanySearchViewModel model) {
    _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    queryController.text = model.query;

    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      drawer: const AppDrawer(),
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png"),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      TitleTextRow(
                          text: model.title, width: _width, height: _height),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10.0,
                      ),
                      Center(
                          child: DescriptionTextRow(
                              text:
                                  "Description",
                              width: _width)),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10.0,
                      ),
                      Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Material(
                              key: ValueKey(model.query),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                              elevation: 10,
                              child: TextFormField(
                                key: _searchKey,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  if (value.length > 3) {
                                    model.setQuery(value);
                                    model.search();
                                  }
                                },
                                obscureText: false,
                                validator: (value) {
                                  return null;
                                },
                                onSaved: (value) {
                                  model.setQuery(value ?? "");
                                },
                                controller: queryController,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                cursorColor: Colors.orange[200],
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,
                                      color: Colors.orange[200], size: 20),
                                  hintText: "ABC Limited",
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      model.searchResult?.items?.length == null
                          ? Text("no results")
                          : Container(
                              child: ListView.builder(
                              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              itemCount: model.searchResult?.items?.length ?? 0,
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                var item = model.searchResult!.items![index];
                                return ListTile(
                                  leading: Icon(Icons.business),
                                  title: Text("Title"),
                                  subtitle:
                                      Text("subtitle"),
                                  onTap: () {
                                    //print to console
                                  },
                                );
                              },
                            )),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Tried moving the result into a widget of its own**
As per the comment below i have tried to move the results into a widget of their own but it still has the same effect

Changed

```
model.searchResult?.items?.length == null
                              ? Text("no results")
                              : Container(
                                  child: ListView.builder(
                                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                  itemCount: model.searchResult?.items?.length ?? 0,
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    var item = model.searchResult!.items![index];
                                    return ListTile(
                                      leading: Icon(Icons.business),
                                      title: Text("Title"),
                                      subtitle:
                                          Text("subtitle"),
                                      onTap: () {
                                        //print to console
                                      },
                                    );
                                  },
                                )),
```

to this

```
  CompanySearchResultWidget(
                          result: model.searchResult ?? SearchResult(),
                          width: _width,
                          height: _height),
```

The results widget

```
class SearchResultWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final SearchResult result;
  final double width;
  final double height;

  const SearchResultWidget(
      {Key? key,
      required this.result,
      required this.width,
      required this.height})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SearchResultWidget> createState() =>
      _SearchResultWidgetState();
}

class _SearchResultWidgetState extends State<SearchResultWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        widget.result.items == null || widget.result.items!.length == 0
            ? Column(
                children: [
                  Text("no results"),
                ],
              )
            : Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: widget.result.items!.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var item = widget.result.items![index];
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.business),
                    title: Text(item.title ?? "No Title"),
                    subtitle: Text("subtitle"),
                    onTap: () {
                      //console
                    },
                  );
                },
              )),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: My best bet is to move the search result UI into its own widget and reduce the usage of keys as they are resource-heavy. By doing so, you restrict the repainting to only the search result widget and not its parent where the search field lives ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've moved it into both a stateless and stateful widget but i'm still getting the same result. Ill update the above

Comment: now you can wrap your child in a [RenderRepaintBoundary()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderRepaintBoundary-class.html) widget. So that you separate the parent's repainting from its child. The email example given in the link I provided here is quite similar situation as yours  read it and let me know if that's solving your issue ;)

Comment: Hi the link in your comment doesnt contain an example that references Email. Have i missed something? Cheers

Comment: "In some cases, it is necessary to place two (or more) repaint boundaries to get a useful effect. Consider, for example, an e-mail application that shows an unread count and a list of e-mails. Whenever a new e-mail comes in, the list would update, but so would the unread count. If only one of these two parts of the application was behind a repaint boundary, the entire application would repaint each time. On the other hand, if both were behind a repaint boundary, a new e-mail would only change those two parts of the application and the rest of the application would not repaint."

Comment: I extracted the above text from the link I shared ;)